# Python Web Search

Tags: python, browser, search-engine

I know it's possible to open up specific URL's with python's **webbrowser** module. Is it possible to use strings as search queries with it, or another module? Say in an engine like Google or Yahoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible - they're just GET requests. So long as you format the URL properly with the query string correct and all (`http://google.com/search?q=query` - look at the site to see what it needs to be), it'll work fine. It's just a URL.

Comment: It is just a URL, but you should take care of HTTP headers as well. `User-agent`, for example.

Comment: @khachik: not relevant - `webbrowser` opens the page in the user's browser. It's not `urllib2.urlopen`.

Comment: My fault, I thought you suggest to open the URL using something else, e.g. `urllib`, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at mechanise if you want to automate webpages. 
You could also generate your own search url and then call it in webbrowser or urllib
See: http://www.our-picks.com/archives/2007/01/30/google-search-urls-revealed-or-how-to-create-your-own-search-url/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search with webbrowser, and allows user to input, this code might helps you.

```
import webbrowser

question = input("Input your question:")
webbrowser.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + str(question))
```